# How to enable javascript in selenium webdriver Chrome using python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open https://www.guidestar.org/ using selenium webdriver but it is able to detect I am a bot. The email I received says that javascript was not enabled so they were blocking my IP address. Can anyone suggest a code to enable javascripts

```
user_agent = 'Chrome/73.0.3683.86'
username = os.getenv("USERNAME")
userProfile = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("user-data-dir={}".format(userProfile))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://www.guidestar.org")
```

I expected the website not to detect that I am a robot

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just add this below line and see.  `options.add_argument("javascript.enabled", True)`

Answer (score 20):

answers provided here won't work.
instead, use

```
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
```

Comment: In the meantime, `chrome_options` has been deprecated. The parameter is now called just `options`.

Comment: This option doesn't work for me, any other solution

Answer (score -1):

As supputuri mentioned, add the following chrome option to your argument:

```
options.add_argument("javascript.enabled", True)
```