# i want to scrape all company name links but getting only first 20 links

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

also after that how to handle "load more" in end to extract all links. as there are total 317 links in the page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

r = requests.get('https://www.tradeindia.com/manufacturers/a3-paper.html')
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div',class_='company-name'):
    links = div.find('a')
    print(links['href'])
```

please someone help me to find the best way to extract all 317 links in the page.

Comment: Your understanding of "all" is different from the webserver's understanding of "all". Do you have JavaScript enabled in the selenium driver? The items > 20 are fetched lazy via ajax. If you don't scroll down it won't work either.

Comment: how to do with selenium driver

Comment: Use the search. Enabling JavaScript in Selenium: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480924/how-to-enable-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver-chrome-using-python

Comment: Scrolling down a page using Selenium: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java