# Selenium - Scroll for screenshots

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot

I have a python script that goes through the UI and fills out a lot of pages.  I take a screenshot, but if the page is longer than the screen, then I miss half of the page.  I tried a longer length, but with the normal pages, it's ridiculous and unusable.  I tried to use ashot, but can't figure out how to add it to my project in pycharm.

Any wisdom or other ideas?  Thanks.

UPDATE on things tried that didn't work (nothing happened on the page:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(continuebtn)
```

Also:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080);")
```

Comment: Well, this sucks,  @DebanjanB - You closed my question and linked two "solutions" for JAVA.  I'm using PYTHON

Comment: Reopened the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a multiple screenshots and scroll through the whole page.

A simple example would be:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time

d = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="PATH TO YOUR DRIVER")
d.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie")
time.sleep(1)
scrollHeight = d.execute_script("return window.scrollMaxY")
index = 0
while d.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset") < scrollHeight:
    d.save_screenshot(PICTURE_PATH+"/"+ FILENAME + str(index).zfill(2) + ".png")
    d.execute_script("window.scrollByPages(1)")
    # maybe call time.sleep in here somewhere to load lazyloaded images
    time.sleep(0.2)
    index += 1
d.quit()
```

Comment: I tried the following (where driver is my chrome browser instance) just to see if I can get it to scroll a page and nothing happens on the page:
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Comment: Have you tried this method with firefox? Alternatively have you tried adding javascript manually in the options (see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480924/how-to-enable-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver-chrome-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480924/how-to-enable-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver-chrome-using-python) )

Comment: We don't use firefox.  Chrome and IE only.  I'll check out the link - thanks!

Comment: The two items on that link didn't work.  One made no change and one caused an error.  Thanks though :/

Comment: I think I got it working!  I had to click elsewhere on the page for it to actually work.